# Netbeans: Like XML Syntax-Highlighting

Tags: xml, netbeans

How could I say to Netbeans that it should highlight *.tmx files like they were xml files?

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a mapping between Fileextension "tmx" and "XML Files" in Tool - Options - Misc - Files.

Comment: I was able to follow @winSharp93 gave and see the desired effect.  I am using NB 6.8 on Win Vista with JDK 6 update 16.